# WPF combobox size on drag GridSplitter

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpf-controls

How can I anchor a combox box so that when I drag the splitter it will size automatically.

I tried using a stackpanel to no avail, and even setting the HorizontalAlignment and HorizontalContentAlignment to stretch; it does not work.

I need the combo box to be as wide as the section is dragged.  In non wpf you just anchored the combo, in wpf that option is not available.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Content="View By" 
            Padding="5" 
            Height="30" />
    <ComboBox Name="ddSelector" 
            Height="25" 
            Width="auto" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
            Margin="16,0,0,0" />
</StackPanel>
```

The stack panel is in row 0 and the grid splitter is in row 1.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="275"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="350"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<GridSplitter Width="5" 
    Margin="0,36,0,5" 
    BorderThickness="4" 
    BorderBrush="Transparent" 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"></GridSplitter>
```

Comment: Where is the GridSplitter located?

Comment: on row 1  within the grid.  row 0 is the above code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms610550.aspx) instead of a StackPanel. This will do.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <Label ../>
   <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" .../>

</Grid>
```

Comment: @nitefrog: Yes, the first is auto or fixed width for the label and the second is *.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0">Some stuff here</Label>
        <GridSplitter 
            ResizeDirection="Rows"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Height="3"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="View By" 
            Padding="5" 
            Height="30" />
            <ComboBox Name="ddSelector" Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
            Margin="16,0,0,0" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```